# Debian netboot via PXE required files

Tags: debian, files, pxe-boot, netboot, tftp

I'm trying to perform a netboot to install Debian on a spare PC I have. I'm using a Windows XP Pro box as the "server". It has a TFTP/DHCP server set up and running on it, but the information on which specific files to put into the root folder of the netboot driectory to allow the Debian install to begin on the "client" machine is vague and confusing, and so far has not worked for me,

As I understand it I should (and have) downloaded the netboot.tar.gz file for Debain and unzip and upack it in the directory of the TFTP server specified. From there I then need to move a few files and alter them ? I'm really not clear on the next step, my experimentation has failed and searching for online help is not proving fruitful. So if someone could explain which files are needed and how they should be organised so the netboot can begin I would be very happy! :)

Thanks in advance..
Ian

EDIT:
Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> As I understand it I should (and have) downloaded the netboot.tar.gz file for Debain and unzip and upack it in the directory of the TFTP server specified.

Right.

> From there I then need to move a few files and alter them ?

Wrong.  The files are fine the way they are, you don't need to touch them.  Just tell the dhcp server to send out "pxelinux.0" as the boot filename.

However, being a windows system I have no idea what it would have done to the symlinks in that tarball.

```
./pxelinux.0 -> debian-installer/i386/pxelinux.0
./debian-installer/i386/pxelinux.cfg/default -> ../boot-screens/syslinux.cfg
./pxelinux.cfg -> debian-installer/i386/pxelinux.cfg
```

You may need to go in and replace those if whatever program you used to unpack the tarball screwed things up.